# Where does Glassfish 3.1 caches JSP files?

Tags: java, caching, glassfish-3

I tried to enable jsp caching globally as indicated in the Oracle Glassfish 3.1 documentation you can find here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beagu.html#beagw

I started my domain domain1 with the usual:

```
asadmin start-domain domain1
```

and then using this

```
asadmin set server-config.web-container.property.jspCachingEnabled="true"
```

to setup the jsp Caching. The GF3.1 Server creates a series of folders in its main directory, namely:

```
{glassfish_home}/domains/domain1/generated/jsp/my_project/xyz_loader
```

but I can't seem to find my compiled JSP in this "loader" directory listing, anybody knows where should I look?

Comment: The location you are using is the correct folder where generated JSPs are stored.  When you deploy your application, try to start it with the following:  `asadmin deploy --precompilejsp=true --force MyApp.war`.  Then, look in that directory and see if you find the JSPs there.

Comment: @RickGrashel - Why not make that an answer?

Comment: Well, I wanted to make sure this actually solved your issue.  Then, I can just make it an answer.  :-)

Comment: @RickGrashel - Got it.  It's not my issue, though ;-)

Comment: @RickGrashel it raised exceptions because it can't find a taglib: JSP Compilation Error: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: file:/usr/share/xyz PWC6117: File "/tags/struts-html" not found. But Taglibs are configured correctly and have always worked.

Comment: Hm, there is something definitely wrong here.  It may have to do with the Glassfish installation itself.  Possible permissions issues.  "/usr/share" is very suspect.  Where is Glassfish installed?  It really should be installed in its own directory with permissions given to its own user.  Something like /opt/glassfish.  You may want to try re-installing Glassfish using a procedure like this: http://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/glassfish/installing-glassfish-311-on-ubuntu.  Even if it isn't Ubuntu, this should work on most forms of Linux with very little adjustment.

Comment: thankyou @RickGrashel I'll try to reinstall or lookup other solutions, Permissions are correctly set to  the owner of Glassfish.